# Exponential of little o

Tags: sequences-and-series, power-series, taylor-expansion

I have a series and the error is of order  $o(x^N)$:

$f(x)=\sum_1^N x^n+ o(x^N)$

Now I want to take exponential on both sides. What happens with the error part?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$e^{f(x)}=e^{\sum_{1}^{N}x^n}e^{o(x^N)}=e^{\sum_{1}^{N}x^n}(1+o(x^N))=e^{\sum_{1}^{N}x^n}+o(x^N)$$

Comment: What if I take an integral  like  $\int_0^{\infty}o(x^N)dx$? Is the answer in that case $o(x^{N+1})$?

Comment: @KAT If you don't know what the $o(x^N)$ actually is you can't take that integral. If you can, the integral is a constant, it can't be $o(x^{N+1})$ unless that constant is zero.

Comment: I meant taking the integral of the above exponential of the series, that is $\int_0^{\infty}e^{f(x)}dx=\int_0^{\infty}e^{\sum_1^Nx^n+o(x^N)}dx$.

Comment: What I am trying to say is that my expression  $\sum_1^{N}x^n+o(x^N)$ comes from $\sum_1^{\infty}x^n=\sum_1^{N}x^n+o(x^N)$.